# Rename files in any deep subfolder like the parent folder and move after to a central folder

Tags: bash, rename, move, synology

I have a problem where I need to rename just certain files after the parent folder and afterwards move these to a central folder. Is there a way to do this?
I would like to run this on a Synology NAS.

```
Root
 |-Subf1
 |  |-File.txt
 |  |-File.doc
 |  |-Subf1subf1
 |  |  |-File.xml
 |  |  |-File.xls
 |  |-Subf1subf2
 |  |  |-File.pptx
 |  |  |-File.docx
 |
 |-Subf2
 |  |-File.txt
 |  |-File.doc
 |  |-Subf2subf1
 |  |  |-File.xml
 |  |  |-File.xls
```

Result should be:

```
Root
 |-Subf1
 |  |-Subf1.txt
 |  |-Subf1.doc
 |  |-Subf1.xml
 |  |-Subf1.xls
 |  |-Subf1.pptx
 |  |-Subf1.docx
 |
 |-Subf2
 |  |-Subf2.txt
 |  |-Subf2.doc
 |  |-Subf2.xml
 |  |-Subf2.xls
```

There is no problem with overwriting files as they all have different extensions.

Comment: Do all the file names start with `File`?

Comment: No, they start different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash

shopt -s globstar  #enabled for '**' to match all files &directories recursively
#shopt -s dotglob  #uncomment to enable to match on hidden files/directories too

cd /path/to/directory/Root
for pathname in ./**/*; do
    [[ -f "$pathname" ]] && echo mv -v -- "$pathname" "${pathname%%/*}/${pathname%%/*}.${pathname##*.}";
done

##then remove remained empty directories
for pathname in ./**/*; do
    [[ -d "$pathname" && -z "$(ls -A -- "$pathname")" ]] && rm -r -- "$pathname";
done
```

- `[[ -f "$pathname" ]]` checks if the `$pathname` is a `f`ile
- `${pathname%%/*}`: Using [shell-parameter-expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), cut the longest suffix from the `pathname` parameter. cuts everything up-to first slash `/` character.
- `${pathname##*.}"`: same, but this cuts the longest prefix from the `pathname` parameter; cuts everything up-to last dot `.` character.
- `[[ -d "$pathname" ]]` checks if the `$pathname` is a `d`irectory
- `... && -z "$(ls -A -- "$pathname")"` then checks if basename of the `pathname` [which was a directory, is empty or not](/q/202243/72456).

remove `echo` when you were happy with the result.

Answer (score 0):

POSIXly:

```
cd Root &&
  LC_ALL=C find . \
    -name '.?*' -prune -o \
      -path './*/*/*' \
      -prune \
      -name '*.*' \
      -type f \
      -exec sh -c '
        ret=0
        for file do
          ext=${file##*.}
          sub=${file%/*/*}
          subname=${sub##*/}
          echo mv -i "$file" "$sub/$subname.$ext" || ret=$?
        done
        exit "$ret"' {} +
```

(remove `echo` if happy)

Empty dirs can be removed afterwards with:

```
find . -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} + 2> /dev/null
```

Or if your `find` supports the non-standard `-empty` and `-delete`:

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

(`-delete` implies `-depth`).